# Create new column in dataframe based on another and matching to another dataset in R

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, data-manipulation, matching

I've the following data frame and I would like to create a new column based on the following conditions:

1. If Price.of.Books is BLANK, R will look up to the matching data frame based on the value in Count.of.Books..Match.
2. If Price.of.Books is not BLANK, it will retain the value

In Excel, it can be done with ifelse() with a vlookup() within the ifelse() function. Is there something similar that can be done in R? So that it will work for larger datasets?

Dataframe

| Index | Grouping | Count.of.Books..Match. | Price.of.Books |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| i1 | A | 1 | BLANK |
| i2 | A | 2 | BLANK |
| i3 | B | 2 | 12 |
| i4 | B | 6 | BLANK |
| i5 | C | 4 | 10 |
| i6 | C | 1 | 11.5 |
| i7 | D | 3 | 8.5 |
| i8 | D | 6 | BLANK |
| i9 | E | 4 | BLANK |

```
df = structure(list(Index = structure(1:9, .Label = c("I1", "I2", 
                    "I3", "I4", "I5", "I6", "I7", "I8", "I9"), class = "factor"), 
                 Grouping = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L
                 ), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), class = "factor"), 
                 Count.of.Books..Match. = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 
                  4L), Price.of.Books = structure(c(5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 
                   4L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("10", "11.5", "12", "8.5", "BLANK"
                   ), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")
```

Matching Data Frame

| Match | Price.of.Books |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 6 |
| 2 | 7 |
| 3 | 8 |
| 4 | 9.5 |
| 5 | 12 |
| 6 | 13 |

```
match = structure(list(Match = 1:6, Price.of.Books = c(6, 7, 8, 9.5, 12, 13)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

The outcome should be the following:

| Index | Grouping | Count.of.Books..Match. | Price.of.Books | New Column |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| i1 | A | 1 | BLANK | 6 |
| i2 | A | 2 | BLANK | 7 |
| i3 | B | 2 | 12 | 12 |
| i4 | B | 6 | BLANK | 13 |
| i5 | C | 4 | 10 | 10 |
| i6 | C | 1 | 11.5 | 11.5 |
| i7 | D | 3 | 8.5 | 8.5 |
| i8 | D | 6 | BLANK | 13 |
| i9 | E | 4 | BLANK | 9.5 |

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  inner_join(match, by = c("Count.of.Books..Match." = "Match")) %>% 
  mutate(Price.of.Books = Price.of.Books.x, 
    new = ifelse(Price.of.Books == "BLANK", Price.of.Books.y, Price.of.Books.x),
    Price.of.Books.x = NULL, Price.of.Books.y = NULL) 

#>   Index Grouping Count.of.Books..Match. Price.of.Books  new
#> 1    I1        A                      1          BLANK  6.0
#> 2    I2        A                      2          BLANK  7.0
#> 3    I3        B                      2             12  3.0
#> 4    I4        B                      6          BLANK 13.0
#> 5    I5        C                      4             10  1.0
#> 6    I6        C                      1           11.5  2.0
#> 7    I7        D                      3            8.5  4.0
#> 8    I8        D                      6          BLANK 13.0
#> 9    I9        E                      4          BLANK  9.5
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Any idea how to create a new column instead of replacing the values?

Comment: My updated solution does that, @Luther_Proton.